# What is the difference between module.exports=require('other') and the same with a temporary variable?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

reproduce link https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-sp5xay?file=index.mjs

Assume we have a project like this:

```
.
├── dep
│   ├── a.mjs
│   ├── b.js
│   └── c.js
└── entry.mjs


// entry.mjs
import { foo } from "./dep/a.mjs";
console.log(foo);

// dep/a.mjs
export * from './b.js'

// dep/b.js
module.exports = require("./c.js"); // 

// why this not working ❌
// const m = require("./c.js"); 
// module.exports = m;


// dep/c.js
exports.foo = "foo";
```

and we run in terminal

```
node entry.mjs
```

it's very confuse it will throw error if in `dep/b.js` we use:

```
// why this not working ❌
const m = require("./c.js"); 
module.exports = m;
```

[image]

if in `dep/b.js` we use:

```
module.exports = require("./c.js");
```

it will work expect!

[image]

`module.exports=require` have something magic? like symlink? if any docs i miss?

The origin of this problem is that I saw the vue3 source code
[vue3 core source code export](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/vue/index.mjs)

Comment: Have you read https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#commonjs-namespaces

Comment: As an example you can update a.mjs to be `export * as foo from './b.js'`. Read more about [Module Namespace Exotic Objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects).

Comment: @morganney Thanks for your answer. But I'm more interested in why  `module.exports = require("./c.js");` can make code work as expect.

The origin of this problem is that I saw the vue3 source code
https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/vue/index.mjs

Comment: I wasn't interested in rewriting the documentation that explained your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `module.exports=require` have something magic?

Yes, it does have some magic. The problem is that you are importing a CommonJS module into an ES module. The latter require a static declaration of exported names, which the former do not provide. See the [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs):

> *When importing [CommonJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#commonjs-namespaces), the `module.exports` object is provided as the default export.*

So just don't do `export * from './b.js'`, rather `import b from './b.js'` then refer to `b.foo` on the CommonJS module object.

However,

> *For better compatibility with existing usage in the JS ecosystem, Node.js in addition attempts to determine the CommonJS named exports of every imported CommonJS module to provide them as separate ES module exports using a static analysis process.*
>
> *[…]*
>
> *The **detection of named exports** is based on common syntax patterns but **does not always correctly detect named exports**. In these cases, using the default import form described above can be a better option.*
>
> *Named exports detection covers many common export patterns, reexport patterns and build tool and transpiler outputs. See [cjs-module-lexer](https://github.com/nodejs/cjs-module-lexer/tree/1.2.2) for the exact semantics implemented.*
>
> <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

And indeed,

```
module.exports = require("./c.js");
```

is one of the "reexport patterns" that is detected, but using a temporary variable

```
const m = require("./c.js"); 
module.exports = m;
```

is not. You just can't use named imports from a CommonJS module that does this. The proper solution to fix this is of course to rewrite the module to ESM syntax and use `export * from "./c.js";`, not any `module.exports` assignments.

Comment: Thanks you so much ! very nice answer! Perfectly explained my doubts and I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, the `module.exports` object is used to specify what a module should make available when it is imported using `require`.

The first statement , `module.exports = require('module')`, sets the module.exports object to the value of the module object that is imported using require. This means that anything that is exported by the `module` module will be made available to the code that imports it.

On the other hand, `module.exports = {...}` sets the module.exports object to an object literal containing the properties and values that should be made available to code that imports the module. This allows you to specify exactly what should be made available from the module, rather than relying on the exports of another module.

For example, suppose you have a module called `myModule` that exports a single function:

```
module.exports = {
  myFunction: () => {
  console.log('Hello, world!');
 }
};
```

This module can then be imported and used like this:

```
const myModule = require('myModule');
myModule.myFunction(); // prints 'Hello, world!'
```

On the other hand, if you set module.exports to the value of another module's exports, like this:

```
module.exports = require('anotherModule');
```

Then the exports of anotherModule will be made available to code that imports myModule. For example:

```
const myModule = require('myModule');
myModule.someFunction(); // calls a function exported by anotherModule
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Your explanation is easy to understand and accept.

But how does node achieve this distinction,  I think node needs to have relevant code logic to handle these differences.

Where can I find relevant code, or documentation or spec

Comment: You can find more information on this by visiting this : https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

Comment: This does not answer the actual question at all.